# surjectivity of a piece-wise function defined as follows

Tags: functions, inverse-function

Define a function $f:\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ by
\begin{equation*}
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x, & \text{if $x$ is even}\\
x+1, & \text{if $x$ is odd}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
for all $x \in \Bbb Z$.
Find a right inverse of $f$ if it exists.

**Attempt:**
$f$ has a right inverse iff $f$ is surjective, so we must check that $f$ is whether surjective or not.
Let $y=f(x)$. Then,
\begin{equation*}
x =  
\begin{cases}
y, & \text{if $y$ is even}\\
y-1, & \text{if $y$ is odd}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
for all $x,y \in \Bbb Z$. Now, consider
\begin{align*}
f(x) &=
\begin{cases}
f(y), & \text{if $y$ is even}\\
f(y-1), & \text{if $y$ is odd}
\end{cases}\\
&=
\begin{cases}
y, & \text{if $y$ is even}\\
(y-1)+1,& \text{if $y$ is odd}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Hence, we see that $f(x) = y$ for all $x \in \Bbb Z$. Thus, $f$ is surjective and therefore, $f$ has a right inverse.

Am I true?

Comment: The image is of $f$ is only even numbers, so $f$ is not surjective

Comment: Oh, I see. The odd numbers doesn't have preimage in $\Bbb Z$, right?

Comment: Right, the odd numbers don't have pre-images in $\Bbb Z$; by the way, your function is not injective either, because $f(1)=f(2)$ but $1\ne2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; the image of $f:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ as you have defined it consists of only even numbers --

$y=f(x)$ is always even --

so $f$ is not surjective -- odd numbers do not have pre-images in $\Bbb Z$ --

so $f$ does not have a right inverse.

By the way, $f$ is not injective either, because $f(1)=f(2)$, but $1\ne2$.